# Renaming staging url of windows azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I have deployed mu mvc-3 application on windows azure and i got this type of staging URL :

```
    http://gt678opUYr56xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudapp.net/
```

I want to rename this with something which we can remmmember like :

```
    http://my-name.cloudapp.net/
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot rename the staging urls. Your application name will be applied to the production slot.

Keep in mind that the staging slot should be used for preparing for a production launch and not for things like QA testing. If this is what you are using the staging slot for, consider setting up another deployment where you can have a name like my-name-qa as your application name.

The cost of the staging slot and another instance running a production slot are the same. Plus, if you are validating functionality, you can use smaller instance sized than you may be using for production.

Comment: does someone know what is powershell command to get this staging slot url ?